# How to reshape a 2d array to 3d matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, multidimensional-array, reshape

I am new to R language, therefore need your assistance.

I have a 2D array of dimension 256* 149.

I want to reshape this 2d array into a 3d matrix in R..therefore the output dimension of the reshaped array will be 16*16*149.

Looking forward to your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `array(c(you_2d_array), c(16,16,149))` the problem is we are not sure how you want the values to be arranged

Comment: @onyambu The `c(…)` is generally unnecessary.

Comment: Another solution: `dim(name2Darray) = c(16, 16, 146)`